# Use accessToken to obtain Dynamics Organization Uri

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth, dynamics-crm

I have a nodejs project that is using adal-node (https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-node) to authenticate via OAuth2 to Dynamics CRM. I have successfully gotten the authorizationUrl, then posted the code to get the accessToken. However, this last response does not return an instanceUrl. So I've been scowering the MSDN pages online for documentation on how to use the accessToken to obtain the correct organization instance Uri. I've tried this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607485.aspx) and just get a 401 "Authorization has been denied for this request" response. Maybe I'm formatting this request improperly? Can someone kindly direct me to some documentation on how to use the valid accessToken I've obtained to retrieve the organization instance Uri for this user? Thanks.

Comment: When I do this GET https://globaldisco.crm.dynamics.com/api/discovery/v1.0/Instances I get a "Authorization has been denied for this request" (JSON). But when I do this GET https://globaldisco.crm.dynamics.com/api/discovery/v1.0/Instances(UniqueName='myorg') I get "Server Error" response in html.

Answer (score 1):

Recently went through this myself, the issue I think you might be experiencing is the resource that is being requested access to when you request your authentication token is incorrect.  While you would think it would be https://globaldisco.crm.dynamics.com/, I actually been successfully with https://disco.crm.dynamics.com/ (ensure to include the trialing slash) as the resource.

If your token is rejected then look at the WWW-Authenticate attribute in the response header and it will indicate the resource you should be requesting.  Similar to this:

```
Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize, resource_id=https://disco.crm3.dynamics.com/
```

After getting the right resource I was able to query the global disco service without issues and even though giving the NA disco resource returned instances from various regions.  This worked on Azure AD tenants started in NA as well as the UK.

I have blogged a full sample here - http://colinvermander.com/2017/01/19/calling-the-dynamics-global-discovery-service/

Comment: This should be marked answer. I was trying to access the global discovery service using an access token obtained for the crm url resource. Changed the resource to https://disco.crm.dynamics.com/ for retrieving the access token and now I'm able to successfully access the global discovery service. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According the description at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607485.aspx, to request against to `https://globaldisco.crm.dynamics.com/api/discovery/v1.0/Instances(UniqueName='myorg')`, you need to replace `myorg` to your own `unique name` of your dynamic crm server.

You can refer to https://www.dynamics-pros.com/support/kb/kb102033 for how to get the unique name.

Comment: Yes, I have obviously tried using my unique name. Also, as mentioned above, I've tried without the UniqueName and get an "Authorization has been denied for this request" error. Ideas?

Comment: [screen shot](https://s15.postimg.org/450z847tn/2016_12_01_09_29_25_am.png)